# How many ways can the statements of 2 processes be interleaved

Tags: process, scheduling

I would like to know, how many ways can the statements of 2 processes be interleaved?
I know what interleaving is but I can't seem to derive a formula.

Comment: You mean, two processes, one having N atomic statements, and the other with M atomic statements, and you want to count the number of ways they can interleave on a single processor? I don't know the answer, but https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29 seems a good start.

Comment: an upper bound (albeit not tight) would be a permutation of the instructions (N+M)!

Answer (score 5):

It's the [Binomial Coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) and it is responsible for the *combinatorial explosion* of possible interleavings that makes analysis of multithreaded code very challenging if not impractical.

So given process `P1` with `N` instructions and process `P2` with `M` instructions you get `N+M over N`, i.e. `(N+M)! / N!M!`, interleavings, which grows exponentially even for relatively small number of instructions per process. For instance, if you have two processes with five instructions each, the number of possible interleavings is `252`. Most real-world applications have, however, millions of instructions, and often more than merely two processes (or threads) involved.

Comment: This does not answer the question. It does not help with deriving the formula.